# Opportunity Notification based on Related Object

Tags: workflow, email-alert, filters

Our Opportunities have a related object, named Billing Schedules. These house  individual billing entries for Opportunities. What I'd like to do is spawn an email notification using a workflow that triggered when a Billing Entry belonging to an Opportunity met certain conditions. Unfortunately, when I choose the criteria, no workflow is triggered, even though it is seemingly meeting the criteria. Below is the criteria I've set. Any idea why this is happening?

```
(Opportunity: Stage EQUALS Closed Lost) AND 
(Billing Schedule:Special/Pre-Billing Schedule EQUALS True) AND 
(Current User: Bypass Workflows EQUALS False)
```

Comment: check the workflow rule is activated or not ??

Comment: In which object have you set the workflow? What is the relation between the opportunity object and the billing schedule object? Master, lookup?, is the Workflow Active?? It is not very clear to me and with a few more details I think we can help you. To start I think that the workflow should be set on the Billing Schedule object. I assume that there is one billing schedule record connected to one opportunity. Maybe you can set a hidden check box on the Billing Schedule records to be true if the Opportunity related have Stage = Close and use it in you logic?

Comment: Are you sure you're running it as a `User` with `Bypass Workflows`?

Comment: I think the problem is that the WF is on Opportunity but you are using a condition on a related object.  If the related object is changing and not the Oppo, then the WF will never execute as SFDC doesn't monitor DML on the related objects when evaluating WFs on the 'target' object

Comment: I have created the workflow on the Billing Schedule object, as the recipients of the email notice are not opposed to receiving a notification for each billing schedule entry upon an Opportunity Stage change. The relationship with the Opportunity is a Master-Detail Relationship. The workflow is active. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the WF is on `BillingSchedule` but you are using a condition on a related object `Opportunity`. If the related object is changing and not the Billing Schedule, then the WF will never execute as SFDC doesn't monitor DML on the related objects when evaluating WFs on the 'target' (i.e. `BillingSchedule`) object.

From the [Workflow doc](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_rules_considerations.htm)

> Workflow rules can be triggered any time a record is saved or created,
>   depending on your rule criteria.

There is [a relevant IDEA](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrIGAA0) worth voting on that would allow for changes in formula fields (including, presumably, cross-object formula fields) to trigger workflows. However, as noted by PM, this would be hard to do.

Your workaround is, via a separate workflow/trigger/process builder, to force the Opportunity to be acted upon by DML/field update when a related  `Billing Schedule` changes.

> Update -based on your comments

If BillingSchedule is a detail to Opportunity, then create a rollup summary field on Opportunity that counts the number of "checked" BillingSchedules, then fire your workflow on Opportunity when stage is closed lost & count of checked billing schedules is >= x

If BillingSchedule is a child via a Lookup relationship to Opportunity, use the [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) (free) package to do the same. Package has a point-and-click UI to define the rollup across the lookup relationship

Comment: The workflow is on the Billing Schedule, not the Opportunity.

Comment: point still applies -- Billing Schedule workflow won't fire unless Billing Schedule undergoes an Update event on itself; if parent Oppo stage goes to closed won, the Billing Schedule doesn't get an update event and hence WF won't execute

Comment: Crop, for that reason, I created an Opportunity Stage formula field on the Billing Schedule object, which inherited the Opportunity's Stage. Then I changed the Workflow to fire off of that Stage being a specific value. That still didn't work.

Comment: yes - if you read carefully the Idea linked above, changes in formula fields, even on the WF target object are not monitored by SFDC and hence won't fire the WF on Billing Schedule.  You need to actually touch Billing Schedule via something that does a DML update

Comment: Understood. Is there anyway to accomplish this today? I will obviously upvote the Idea, but I need to accomplish the end-desired result in some more easy fashion. If the reverse can be done, I am happy to do it that way. For example, if I can fire the Workflow off the Opportunity object, upon reaching a specific Stage, that's great, but I only want to fire it off if a checkbox on ANY of the billing schedule entries (related object) are checked. Any advice?

Comment: i made some updates to my answer.